# Making data stationary for ARIMA model using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am using ARIMA model to forecast future time series values. Prior to doing that, I need to make my data seasonal free, stationary and detrend. I went through numerous articles related to making data stationery. And, till now I have written following code but still does not able to remove seasonality as well as stationarity. The sample of data is as follows,

```
        DATE             X
 1992-01-01 03:00:00    10.2
 1992-01-01 06:00:00    10.4
 1992-01-01 09:00:00    11.8
 1992-01-01 12:00:00    12.0
 1992-01-01 15:00:00    10.4
 1992-01-01 18:00:00    9.4
 1992-01-01 21:00:00    10.4
 1992-01-02 00:00:00    13.6
 1992-01-02 03:00:00    13.2
 1992-01-02 06:00:00    11.8
 1992-01-02 09:00:00    12.0
 1992-01-02 12:00:00    12.8
 1992-01-02 15:00:00    12.6
 1992-01-02 18:00:00    11.0
 1992-01-02 21:00:00    12.2
 1992-01-03 00:00:00    13.8
 1992-01-03 03:00:00    14.0
 1992-01-03 06:00:00    13.4
 1992-01-03 09:00:00    14.2
 1992-01-03 12:00:00    16.2
 1992-01-03 15:00:00    13.2
 1992-01-03 18:00:00    13.4
 1992-01-03 21:00:00    13.8
 1992-01-04 00:00:00    14.8
 1992-01-04 03:00:00    13.8
 1992-01-04 06:00:00    7.6
 1992-01-04 09:00:00    5.8
 1992-01-04 12:00:00    4.4
 1992-01-04 15:00:00    5.6
 1992-01-04 18:00:00    6.0
 1992-01-04 21:00:00    7.0
 1992-01-05 00:00:00    6.8
 1992-01-05 03:00:00    3.4
 1992-01-05 06:00:00    5.8
 1992-01-05 09:00:00    10.6
 1992-01-05 12:00:00    9.2
 1992-01-05 15:00:00    10.6
 1992-01-05 18:00:00    9.8
 1992-01-05 21:00:00    11.2
 1992-01-06 00:00:00    12.0
 1992-01-06 03:00:00    10.2
 1992-01-06 06:00:00    9.0
 1992-01-06 09:00:00    9.0
 1992-01-06 12:00:00    8.6
 1992-01-06 15:00:00    8.4
 1992-01-06 18:00:00    8.2
 1992-01-06 21:00:00    8.8
 1992-01-07 00:00:00    10.0
 1992-01-07 03:00:00    9.6
 1992-01-07 06:00:00    8.0
 1992-01-07 09:00:00    9.6
 1992-01-07 12:00:00    10.8
 1992-01-07 15:00:00    10.2
 1992-01-07 18:00:00    9.8
 1992-01-07 21:00:00    10.2
 1992-01-08 00:00:00    9.4
 1992-01-08 03:00:00    11.4
 1992-01-08 06:00:00    12.6
 1992-01-08 09:00:00    12.8
 1992-01-08 12:00:00    10.4
 1992-01-08 15:00:00    11.2
 1992-01-08 18:00:00    9.0
 1992-01-08 21:00:00    10.2
 1992-01-09 00:00:00    8.2
```

The above datasets have 'X' value for the 20 years in Dataframe format (total size=70K) with 3 hrs mean period [Original data fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x75wc.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x75wc.png). Since the dataset is huge and complex hence did data preparation, in which used monthly mean value for entire data,[monthly_mean_data [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jNsu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jNsu.png) using following code,

```
df_monthly = dataset.resample('M', on='DATE').mean()  # dataset contains DATE and x values
indexedDataset=monthly.copy()

test_stationarity(indexedDataset)   # using test_stationarity function created by me that includes adfuller function and rolloing mean analysis

## Estimating trend
indexedDataset_logScale=np.log(indexedDataset)    # taken log in index datasets

# taking the difference of moving an average and actual number of 'X', taking the log

movingAverage = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).mean()    # 12 for monthly
movingSTD = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).std()

#Differencing
datasetLogScaleMinussMovingAverage=indexedDataset_logScale-movingAverage
# removing NAN values
datasetLogScaleMinussMovingAverage.dropna(inplace=True)
datasetLogScaleMinussMovingAverage.head(12)

test_stationarity(datasetLogScaleMinussMovingAverage)
```

After doing all these when I ran my `test_stationarity` function, I got [this [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLJ6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLJ6.png) which suggest my rolling mean and std are not constant hence data still stationary. Therfore, written following code to make data stationary

```
    exponentialDecayWeightAverage=indexedDataset_logScale.ewm(halflife=365,min_periods=0,adjust=True).mean()
datasetLogScaleMinussMovingExponentialDecayAverage = indexedDataset_logScale-exponentialDecayWeightAverage
datasetLogScaleMinussMovingExponentialDecayAverage.dropna()   

# shifting the value into time series so that we can used it for forecasting

datasetLogDiffShifting=indexedDataset_logScale-indexedDataset_logScale.shift()   # d=2

datasetLogDiffShifting.dropna(inplace=True)

test_stationarity(datasetLogDiffShifting)
```

And, this resulted in [fig [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8J6w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8J6w.png). This again suggests rolling mean and std are not constant and hence not stationary. Could anyone help me,  1) weather taking monthly mean value instead of all data is appropriate or not? 2) how to make my data stationary

Comment: This seems to me more of a statistical/method problem rather than a code question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you explain me. it more, what you mean my your above sentences ?

Comment: The question might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/